# Is it okay to loop through a blank array or should I put in a value first?

Tags: c

Do I need to store a value into an array before I loop through it? It works correctly without storing a value, but which one is the "right" way?

```
int ary3[1000000] = {};
//int ary3[100000] = {0}; //or should I store a value first

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(ary3) / sizeof(int); i++) {
    printf("%d = %d\n", i, ary3[i]);
}
```

I've made a correction. I don't want to store any values first. I just want to display out the indices immediately after declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not okay to not initialize an array unless you are somehow keeping track of which indexes are initialized and which are not.  The reason is that you will access some garbage or memory that you are not allowed access to.  Also, if other programmers where to start where you left off, they might get some weird results.

Also, avoid magic numbers.

Comment: Thanks! This is the concise answer I was looking for

Answer (score 4):

You don't *have to* initialize the array, provided you can follow one basic rule:

**Your program must always know which members of the array have been initialized before attempting to access them.**

<s>In your case, you're looping through the entire array at first and setting initial values based on their index. After your first `for` loop, all the values in your array have been initialized, so you can continue without any checks.</s> *Removed based on the edit to the question.*

However, if you were only *partially* initializing the array at first, all the code following that (at least, until you could determine that the array had been fully initialized) would have to have some sort of safeguard in place to prevent you from using an uninitialized position in the array.

In short, if you can't be *100% certain* that your code won't try to read an uninitialized member of the array, make sure your first step is to initialize the entire array to a sane value.

Answer (score 0):

You have only displayed a snippet of code, and the answer depend on some of the thing that you don't show.

If the array is "global" (i.e. has static duration), it will be initialized to zero by the system. In this case, it really does not matter it you put in the value or not.

On the other, if the array is local, if you don't initialize it, it will contain garbage. If you initialize to zero (even if you only have a simple initializer like `{0}`, the runtime environment will initialize it. Hence, you plan to initialize it your self, you will take a double penalty if you store a value into it first.

Comment: The array is located within main() { ... }, in this case would it be initialized to 0 generally?

Comment: No, if it does not have an initializer, the content will be undefined.